# IntelliJ multiple Modules which lie in the same package-namespace?

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

I try to migrate from eclipse to IntelliJ IDEA 13.
Up until now I had multiple eclipse projects which are all in the namespace xxx.yyy.zzz. 
(Kind of a plugin infrastructure with one main app and plugins using the same namespace...).
After migrating the eclipse projects to IntelliJ modules everything builds fine, until I open a File of the main app. IntelliJ then complains: "Package name "xxx.yyy.zzz.Foo" does not correspond to the file path "src.xxx.yyy.zzz.Foo", and therefor also fails to find the imports depending on this package.

This happens even though I set the source-folder to src. The weird thing is: This only happens to some of the imported modules, others (in the same namespace) are fine. 
And also the modules which show this behavior start behaving like this only after I import other modules (so I guess there is some problem with conflicting package-namespaces in modules?)

Any input would be highly appreciated, since I can't find a solution to this.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you set multiple source folders, each one to src(/main/java)? Could you include a screenshot of your project structure's settings?

Comment: Yes, each module has its own src folder! Here's a Screenshot of the main app's src-configuration (hope you meant that?). http://imgur.com/iTn7YsK

Comment: In IntelliJ, you should create one new project (comparable to Eclipse's workspace), and create different modules in it (modules are comparable to Eclipse's projects, if you want so). If would suggest you to use a build tool like Maven - this could make it easier to define each module. At least I would know how to do this in IntelliJ with Maven ;)

Comment: Actually I did this - without maven - one project, multiple modules.

Comment: There are cases where you can safely ignore this error, and the project will still compile.

Comment: @tnull did you find any solution ?